# A problem of Erdős on convergence of $\sum (-1)^nn/p_n$ and equidistribution of $\pi(n)$ modulo 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Erdős asked<sup>1</sup> whether the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n}{p_n}$$ converges.

Here, $p_n$ denotes the n-th prime.
I can show that this series converges simultaneously with the series $\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\pi(m)}}{m \log m} $ by using the prime number theorem and estimating the difference between $ \frac{n}{p_n} $ and $ \frac{n+1}{p_{n+1}}$ for odd and even $n$.  Hence, the problem comes down to understanding the equidistribution of the  parity of the prime counting function $\pi(m)$.

Let $E_n = \{ m \leq n : \pi(m) \equiv 0  \mod 2 \}$ and $O_n = \{ m \leq n : \pi(m) \equiv 1 \mod 2 \}$. Then one naturally asks:

> Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|E_n|}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|O_n|}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$?

If this result is true, can we prove convergence?

---

<sup>1</sup>See, for example: 
Guy R.K. *Unsolved problems in number theory* (2nd ed., Springer, 1994), [page 203, E7](https://books.google.com/books?id=EbLzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA203)
or Steven R.Finch: *Mathematical Constants* (Cambridge University Press, 2003), [page 96](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA96).

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, Mustafa: I suggest to erase all previous comments, obsolete now

Comment: The convergence cannot be formally deduced if the $1/2$ distribution result holds. To be more precise, it is an exercise that there exists a $\{0,1\}$-equidistributed (in the given sense) sequence $(s(n))$ such that $\sum \frac{(-1)^{s(n)}}{n\log n}$ does not converge.

Comment: Intuitively, the convergence requires the sequence  $ (-1)^{\pi(n)} $ to be "close to"  $ (-1)^{n} $. So perhaps one should find a tight upper bound (probably an  $ O(1) $ ) for the quantity  $ \vert\vert E(n)\vert-\vert O(n)\vert\vert $.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN $|E_n| - |O_n|$ is certainly not bounded, because there are arbitrarily large gaps in the primes.

Comment: @User Start from $s_0(n)=n$ (modulo 2). This one is equidistributed and the series converges. Now consider $X=\{2\lfloor n\log n\rfloor:n\ge 4\}$ and $Y=X\cup (X+1)$. Then $Y$ has density zero but $(1/n\log n)$ is already non-summable on $Y$, while the restriction of $(-1)^n/(n\log n)$ converges for partials sums restricted to $Y$. So, define $s(n)=s_0(n)$ for $n\notin Y$ and $s(n)=0$ for $n\in Y$. Since $s=s_0$ on a set of density 1, the equidistribution still holds. But the contribution on $Y$ (and convergence outside $Y$) will force divergence of the series $(-1)^{s(n)}/n\log n$.

Comment: I was able to use the equivalence mentioned by the OP in a recent paper on this topic. https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07205